# Test case of MTableHeader of @material-table/core using jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, material-table

Can anyone help me on this please?
I am trying to write different test cases for the component TableHeader using jest, But I am unable to move further because of this issue. The issue is of **@material-table/core** library. When I am trying to render **MTableHeader** inside my test case I am unable to render it. Showing how am I doing this:

```
import { MTableHeader } from '@material-table/core';
import React from 'react';
import { memo } from 'react';
import {
  Skeleton,
  TableCell as UITableCell,
  TableRow as UITableRow,
} from '@mui/material';

const TableHeader = memo((props) => {
  const { columns } = props;
  console.log('columns: ', columns, props);

  return !columns.length ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <UITableRow>
        {[...Array(7).keys()].map((_, i) => (
          <UITableCell key={i} component="td" scope="row">
            <Skeleton animation="pulse" variant="text" height={40} key={i} />
          </UITableCell>
        ))}
      </UITableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MTableHeader {...props} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

export default TableHeader;
```

This is the component for which I am writing the test cases

now, My case is when I am passing the prop columns inside the TableHeader component it should render the MTableHeader from library but it is not

my test cases =>

```
    const columns = [
      { title: 'Column 1', field: 'col1' },
      { title: 'Column 2', field: 'col2' },
      { title: 'Column 3', field: 'col3' },
    ];
    // const localization = {};

    // MTableHeader.mock = jest.fn(() => <div data-testid="mock-mtable-header" />);

    render(<TableHeader columns={columns} />);

    columns.forEach((column) => {
      const columnElement = screen.getByText(column.title);
      expect(columnElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

I tried with different methods one is mocking the MTableHeader which's not working for me it gives nothing is returned from the render

```
  const MockMTableHeader = jest.fn(() => <div> some test</div>);
  return { MTableHeader: MockMTableHeader };
});
```